# A list that returns the elements of a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
word_list = ['dog', 'downvote', 'gestapo']
```

I would like this:

```
['d', 'o', 'g', 'w', 'n', 'v', 't', 'e', 's', 'a', 'p']
```

This is my code;

```
[list(word_list[j]) for j in range(len(word_list))]
```

This code returns this:

```
[['d', 'o', 'g'], ['d', 'o', 'w', 'n', 'v', 'o', 't', 'e'], ['g', 'e', 's', 't', 'a', 'p', 'o']]
```

Instead I tried this:

```
[(word_list[j])[k] for j in range(len(word_list)) for k in len(word_list[j])]
```

This returns an error: `'int' object is not iterable`

I would like to rectify and update my final attempt so that I get the desired output.

Comment: The means that you can loop over an integer. E.g. Integers aren't utterable data structures.

Comment: `for k in len(word_list[j])` should be `for k in word_list[j]`. [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) returns an integer, which you can't iterate. Also, `(word_list[j])[k]` should just be `k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original order of characters (as in the words from `word_list`):

```
def f(seq):
    seen = set()
    for x in (x for word in word_list for x in word):
        if x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
            yield x 

list(f(word_list)) # ['d', 'o', 'g', 'w', 'n', 'v', 't', 'e', 's', 'a', 'p']
```

If you don't, just construct the `set` using set comprehension:

```
{x for word in word_list for x in word} # {'e', 'd', 'n', 'a', 't', 'w', 'o', 'g', 'v', 's', 'p'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I think you are all technically correct.
The right way to do it in python would probably be:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*word_list))
```

Comment: Except `*wordlist` goes against PyLint recommendation: [star-args (W0142)](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html)

Comment: You can always replace that with set(chain.from_iterable(word_list)) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
k=[]
for j in [list(i) for i in word_list]:
    k += j
print list(set(k))
>>>>['d', 'o', 'g', 'w', 'n', 'v', 't', 'e', 's', 'a', 'p']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add), and a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```
>>> import operator

>>> words = ['dog', 'downvote', 'gestapo']

>>> set(reduce(operator.add, words))
set(['a', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'o', 'n', 'p', 's', 't', 'w', 'v'])
```

If you want it to be a list:

```
>>> list(set(reduce(operator.add, words)))
['a', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'o', 'n', 'p', 's', 't', 'w', 'v']
```

Note: it's not alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is important, a simple way is to use(abuse?) an OrderedDict

```
>>> word_list = ['dog', 'downvote', 'gestapo']
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(word_list)).keys()
['d', 'o', 'g', 'w', 'n', 'v', 't', 'e', 's', 'a', 'p']
```